# How to get the SIM number (ICCID) of a modem using AT commands

Tags: serial-port, 3g, at-command, modem

I'm trying to get the `SIM number` ([`ICCID`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subscriber_identity_module#ICCID), not [`IMSI`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_mobile_subscriber_identity)) of my 3G Huawei  E5830 modem using [`AT commands`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayes_command_set) (also called `Hayes command set`).

Unfortunately, it's not specified in the modem formal documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works with `AT+CRSM` and also `AT+CSIM`.

Comment: there are a few more commands that do that, s.a - AT!ICCID. each device supports it's own at commands, to get those commands use AT+CLAC

Comment: I try to use that commands but i allways get CME ERROR: 50, i'm usign a modem huawei e173, do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 9):

Try "AT^ICCID?". tested on Huawei E173.

Comment: This works on my EM820W as well, but with the digits pair-wise swapped, eg 
AT^ICCID?
^ICCID: "981344xyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxy" 
where the number printed on the sim is 893144yxyxyxyxyxyx etc.

Comment: Also works with Huawei ME906s-158 with the following command: `mmcli -m 0 --command AT^ICCID?` after restarting NetworkManager and ModemManager in debug mode

Answer (score 9):

for sim900 AT+CCID
gives CCID.
e.g.89912200000280775659

The first two digits (89 in the example) refers to the Telecom Id. 
The next two digits (91 in the example) refers to the country code (91-India). 
The next two digits (22 in the example(MNC of IDEA)) refers to the network code.

Answer (score 4):

AT+ICCID  on galaxy S4 in modem mode.

Answer (score 2):

AT+CICCID on an Iridium satellite modem.