# How to whitelist on sim-numbers with mmcli (ModemManager DBus-powered Linux daemon API)

Tags: linux, whitelist, sim-card, 4g, mmcli

I want to have modem manager being enabled/working on 1 specified sim-card. Basically an whitelisting option for sim-cards will do the trick.

I already looked at the following: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/ModemManager/man/1.0.0/mmcli.8.html but I couldnt find it. I understand that there is only an option for whitelisting devices, not for sim-cards.

If I could get the current sim-number somewhere, then maybe I can create some whitelisting logic by myself. But also getting the current sim-number that is in use/available seems hard to get.

Thanks in advance.

Working on: linux/debian OS

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4204018/5128464) for AT command. Then you will need a way to send it as the `--command` option of mmcli is only available when ModemManager is run in debug mode.